vulnerabilities when creating react app, how to fix it?
Each time I create a react up I get:
8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
I tried to fix it with npm audit fix, but it didn't change anything. I tried to fix it with npm audit fix --force, but it became worse - it showed me 162 vulnerabilities.
Is it critical to fix it? If yes, then how can I do it?

Can you also mention the initial critical issues mentioned ?

create-react-app has been deprecated for more than a year. Do not use this to create a new react app for exactly reasons such as above, it is not receiving (security) updates. Read the docs on how to create a new React app here

create-react-app has sunset and react-scripts are now deprecated, there is currently no option to setup a CRA app without the vulnerabilities, you should use another alternative to create your app, like vite:
npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react

You can find more about how to setup an app using vite here: Vite scaffolding
